# Improving XML Parsing Performance

Tags: xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I've few XML Documents with bunch of XPath queries. I want only the app I design to change the XML doc :). I 've mechanisms to check the integrity of the document and protect someone screwing around.

Now, XML Parsing with C# .Net doesn't give the performance I'm happy about.

The options I have are.

1. Use a new parser (Even port to C++).
2. Write a Schema.( It might take a long long time ). Does it improve parsing performance?
3. Playing around with more .Net classes or libraries. XMLReader is what I'm using now

Can someone tell me which will make me smile more after the time I spend on.

Updated some Info:
I want to only parse and read some/all attributes. Writing are changing the doc is not what I want. 
Might want XSD support later on. (Donno what future holds for me)

Current Performance: 50 MB of XML in 14 seconds in 1000 files.

Opening, closing of files also takes some time I guess !!(It is included)

I'm looking for 1/2 the time of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you read [Improving XML Performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647804.aspx#scalenetchaptch09%20_topic8)?

Without seeing some code which shows exactly what you are doing and timing it is hard to comment on what is slow, but I suspect that it is not the parsing itself which is slow.

Comment: Thanks. I'm reading it and profiling the figures individually for IO. I'll accept this as the answer and close the question. I was being too vauge.

Answer (score 1):

It is not recommended that you create a new parser, when Microsoft has already defined one. The use of a schema (with XmlSerializer) greatly simplifies the coding process. In addition, the use of sgen (XML Serializer Generator) allows to `creates an XML serialization assembly for types in a specified assembly in order to improve the startup performance of a XmlSerializer when it serializes or deserializes objects of the specified types`.
In addition, you can use `xsd.exe` tool to generate the schema from an xml file. The generated schema can be modified to suit your taste.

**More information**

- [XML Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950721.aspx)
- [XML Serializer Generator Tool (Sgen.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk3w6240%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
- [XML Schema Definition Tool (Xsd.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Does schema improve the performance? I'm not serializing anything.  Thanks for the xsd generator. The XML has almost 1000 tags and attributes. Its a mess after I generate an schema.  I was thinking of using [pugixml](http://code.google.com/p/pugixml/) with a wrapper

Comment: @Vignesh, Can you post a sample of the xml file? If you the xsd, then the flow is: 1. Use xsd to generate a class definition from the schema, 2. Use XmlSerializer to deserialize the xml (load the xml into memory), 3. Use the xml elements.

Comment: @Vignesh, XPath is a faster way to query an XML. But it is only helpful, if you know the location of the information you want to query beforehand. But also note that the pre generation of the serializer (using sgen) can significantly boost the startup performance of the application (though the memory consumption remains the same).

Comment: Thank you devendra. I understood that part.  I'll try using Serializer and using the schema.

Answer (score 0):

First, I wonder if you're using the term "XML parser" correctly. I ask because many people refer incorrectly to the processing they do on the XML, after parsing (for example using XSLT) as if it were part of the parsing.

Secondly, what performance are you getting from the parser, and what performance do you require? Any exercise in performance improvement should start with these two numbers, and there is no point making any suggestions until we know how much they differ.

Validating your source document against a schema will generally increase parsing time rather than decreasing it.

Comment: I updated some info. I'm just parsing it,running xpath queries. Now my observation is TinyXML and Pugixml don't have XSD support, which I might need in future. I'm considering if XSD based validation is plugable in future.